# Enable HSTS with Spring Boot does not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, hsts

- I have a spring boot application
- I would like to enable HSTS

I added the documented settings to my SecurityConfiguration (see below),
but HSTS header is not appearing.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.headers()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .preload(false)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);
```

I can't find the header in Chrome Developer Tools (F12 -> Network -> Headers  -> Response Header) when accessing the page nor when testing with official site https://gf.dev/hsts-test

[image]

Comment: Is your backend using `https`?

Comment: The spring boot application runs under http 8080, but a Dispatchserver runs https which routes the request to spring boot. I see the problem with http. Is there a way to tell Spring boot to set the HSTS Header also in case of http?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Spring Security only adds the HSTS header if the connection is secure (https). See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/headers.html#headers-hsts).

However, you can change the `RequestMatcher` as you want, like so:

```java
http.headers()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .preload(false)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)
                .requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE);
```